# Vb console questions how to

Tags: vb.net, vba, console

Right I want to know how to, if possible to use code that has already been read or an effective way for doing it.

I want to be able to use the location variable without having to write it out hundreds of times.
Hopefully you understand what im talking about. I want to be able to leave the shop and the come back to this            console.writeline("where would you like to go")         part.

```
        Console.WriteLine("where would you like to go")
        Console.WriteLine("1 - The shop")
        location = Console.ReadLine()
    Loop Until location = "1"
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("***********************************The Shop***********************************")
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.writeline("Shopkeeper: how can I help you")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to try a more structured approach. Use a new class called `Location` that contains information about each location (example has a name and a list of possible destinations). This can of course be further advanced with possible interactions and such things.

```
Public Class Location
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Destinations As List(Of String)
    Public Sub New(Name As String, Destinations As String())
        Me.Name = Name
        Me.Destinations = New List(Of String)
        Me.Destinations.AddRange(Destinations)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You first make a list of locations in your game. I made three, the street, the shop and the shop's back room (mysterious!).
On each iterations you display a list with the locations from the objects you made and let the user choose one. You then change the location based on the name.
That way you can easily add locations and interconnections.
You don't really want to hardcode every step the user can take.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        'Create locations
        Dim Locations As New List(Of Location)
        Locations.Add(New Location("Shop", {"Street", "Back Room"}))
        Locations.Add(New Location("Street", {"Shop"}))
        Locations.Add(New Location("Back Room", {"Shop"}))
        'Define a starting location
        Dim CurrentLocation As String = "Street"
        Do
            Console.WriteLine("You are at: " & CurrentLocation)
            Console.WriteLine("Destinations: ")
            'Bit of Linq to select the location by name from your defined locations
            Dim ThisLocation As Location = (From l As Location In Locations Where l.Name = CurrentLocation Select l).First
            'Display the possible destinations from here
            For i = 0 To ThisLocation.Destinations.Count - 1
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("-{0}- {1}", (i + 1).ToString, ThisLocation.Destinations(i)))
            Next
            'Read user input for a the destination he wants to travel to
            Dim NewLocation As Integer = -1
            Do
                Console.Write(" Go to: ")
                Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, NewLocation)
            Loop Until NewLocation >= 1 AndAlso NewLocation <= ThisLocation.Destinations.Count
            'Change the current location
            CurrentLocation = ThisLocation.Destinations(NewLocation - 1)
        Loop

    End Sub

End Module
```